# Ubuntu 16.04 not detecting the second screen

Tags: multiple-monitors

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS cannot detect the second screen.

I connect my PC with to two screens, one from the VGA and the other from DVI-D to VGA. The two screens show exactly the same picture. I tried to set the screens by System Settings --> Display; however, there is only one (pink) monitor shown in the dialogue window. The `Mirror Screens` checkbox and `Built-in Display` selection are grayed out and there is no response when I click the `Detect monitors` button.

What can I do to solve the problem? Thanks.

EDIT:

1. The output of `xrandr`:

   xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
   Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
   default connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
      1280x1024     77.00*
2. The output of `sudo lshw -C display`:

   ```
   *-display UNCLAIMED
      description: VGA compatible controller
      product: Richland [Radeon HD 8570D]
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
      physical id: 1
      bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
      configuration: latency=0
      resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fef00000-fef3ffff
   ```

Comment: Add to your question the output of `xrandr` when both screens are connected please.

Comment: The outputs are appended.

Comment: There is some problem, maybe with the graphic card drivers. Producer and model?

Comment: The outputs of `sudo lshw -C display` are also appended.

Comment: As I thought, the card is a AMD. AMD does not support Linux anymore with the proprietary drivers (in detail: the new X servers), so you are stuck with the open ones, as explained [in the Release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#fglrx). There is a LOT of development going on about these open drivers, that will land on 16.04 with the first point-release. I personally suggest to you to go back to 14.04, and wait until it automatically suggests you to switch. At this point probably you will be able to install 16.04 and everything will be fine with the graphic card.

Comment: After a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04.1, the problem is "solved". However, Ubuntu has problems detecting two screens **automatically**. Every time I start the system, I have to go through `System Settings` > `Display` to let Ubuntu know that two monitors are connected. In that dialogue, two monitors will show up and after I click `Apply`, everything will work fine.